# Why are there problems with the django application (database, styles) when running on nginx?

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, docker-compose

I am practicing running django from luck on the nginx server, I wrote all the necessary configurations to run the application in which the production and developer versions are located and faced the problem that in the developer version everything works fine for me and in the production version the styles on the entire project are not loaded for me ( I have seen many similar questions, but I have everything written down as in the answers to them), and also my Postgres database does not work on production and gives me an error that it does not exist
I provide code fragments
settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
    version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U hello_django -h db"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Dockerfile.prod:

```
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh entrypoint.prod.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
----------------------------------------
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

nginx: Dockerfile nginx.conf

```
FROM nginx:1.25

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
-------------------------------
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

I also attach errors in the database and lack of styles:
[image][image]

I apologize if there is a lot of information, I just want to provide as much information as possible to get an answer, I will be grateful for any advice

Comment: I fixed the error with the styles, so it no longer makes sense at all, but what to do with the base, I have no ideas

Comment: 1) Do not use images copy and paste as text. 2) The image error text is telling you the problem the database `hello_django_prod` does not exist. So either you are connecting to wrong cluster or the database has not been created in the correct cluster.